# How do I disable enter animation in angular js version 1.2.0

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have used the example on 
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

I am able to get the animations to work. But I would like to ONLY have the leave animation. Is there a way to do it? I have tried to get rid of the `.repeat-item.ng-enter` in my css, unfortunately did not work. Any insights?
Thanks!
My Javascript:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in m.itemList" class="repeat-item">
```

My CSS:

```
.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:1s linear all;
  transition:1s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave,
.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

My updated CSS:

```
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:1s linear all;
  transition:1s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave{
  opacity:1;
}
```

In my updated CSS, I got rid of anything related to `ng-enter` but still got the animation for entering.

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2):

For me It's working !

here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/egIpovAB/2/edit)

```css
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:1s linear all;
  transition:1s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I tried it again, did not work for me. I am having some difficulties finding the official docs for the animation with example.